# Xcode doesn't read recent data

Tags: xcode, git, github, xcode14

I was rebase my branch from `feature/...` to `develop` and while resolve conflicts and merging, problem shows up.

At the branch, there are latest changed commits and I pushed them.
So, If I pull from `feature/...`, nothing changed.

- git pull origin feature/...
  [image]

But the files and codes inside of latest commits are not showing in Xcode and deleted group is showing.

- Xcode

[image]

I think Xcode is referencing improperly.
How can I fix this problem?